Limiting the rows in a window function with a column that isn't the ordering column
We ingest a given file every day and track the lines volume in a monitoring table.
SELECT
 observation_date,
  flow_name,
  volume,
FROM
  `monitoring_table`

And I was querying it trying to learn more about advanced window function usage.
One usecase I wanted to implement was 'the day of the lowest volume up until the current day', but all I managed to figure out was how to find 'the day of the absolute lowest volume across all days'.
  NTH_VALUE(observation_date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY volume) AS day_of_lowest_volume,

And adding any 'ROWS BETWEEN' statement would only impact the scope of the volumes, and not the days.
Is there any way I could add this scope limit on the observation_date inside the window function ?

Try use over(partition by flow_name order by volume desc)

I'm not seeing why this would need a window function

my first idea would  be an outer apply insteadof a window function

@Andrew indeed it can be done without a window function, but I'm trying to achieve this result with one as a way to learn about them.
